# UTF-8 and charcters in Java and Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, utf-8, ascii

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String str = "अ";
    byte[] bytes = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
    for (byte b : bytes) {
      System.out.print(b + "\t");
    }
    String hindi = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println("\nHindi = " + hindi);
    System.out.println((int) 'अ');
  }
```

OUTPUT:

```
-32 -92 -123    
Hindi = अ
2309
```

I need explanation on those three outputs. Especially the last one.

Also, I copy paste this character`अ` from a web page. How do I type it manually in Eclipse IDE? For example, ALT + 65 will give 'A' but ALT + 2309 does not give me 'अ' (I copy paste this again).

Comment: Under Windows there is the accessory system tool Character Map with which you may browse through the character tables, click and copy strings together. 2309 is the Unicode number, in Java (base 16) writable as `"\u0905"`. Char Map displays the Unicode values too as tooltip. The are Unicode characters which need two 16 bit Java chars, hence you might opt for String instead of char there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The first print:

  See [public byte[] getBytes(Charset charset)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.nio.charset.Charset%29):

  > Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the given charset,
  >   storing the result into a new byte array.
- The second print:

  See [public String(byte[] bytes,
            Charset charset)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29):

  > Constructs a new String by decoding the specified array of bytes using
  >   the specified charset.
- The third print:

  See [this link](http://www.codetable.net/decimal/2309):

  You're printing the *decimal code* of it, which is 2309.

The links provided above should help you to understand the output you're getting in each case.

Comment: I copy paste that character. Now I want to type it myself from keyboard

Comment: If you want to print it, you can simply: `System.out.println("अ");`

Comment: I want to enter that character myself in my editor. For example, ALT + 65 will give 'A' but ALT + 2309 does not give me "अ" (I copy paste this again).

Comment: @Mawia [you need to enable unicode from registry](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm), reboot, and then, while holding `ALT` down, press `+905`, that is, while holding ALT down, press, +, 9, 0, 5. The `+` at the beginning is necessary. And the code point must be entered in hexadecimal, with 0-9 coming from numpad and a-f coming from normal keyboard letters. 2309 is 905 in hexadecimal. See me do it: अअअ

Comment: @Esailija I tried that and my Eclipse stopped working :( I messed it up. I will try again. I'm confused with key, string value, binary value etc..

Comment: @Mawia it works for me in this comment textarea, maybe start with that. Works for me in Eclipse too. Make sure you do the registry setting correctly and reboot after that. The type is `REG_SZ`. Here's a screenshot from my `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Control Panel/Input Method` http://i.imgur.com/8dHpiVS.png. `REG_SZ` is `New -> String Value`.

Comment: @Esailija WOW! It works. अ आ इ Thanks. Expect to see some rep ups soon :)

Comment: @Mawia the rep will be undone because there is fraud detection :P You can get away with 1-2 upvotes at most I think. You are actually doing harm to me because I am now repcapped and can't gain reputation legitimately. Then at the end of day, all your upvotes will be removed. :P If you could cancel them that would be cool :)

Comment: @Esailija Happened to me last night :D

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you need to type letter's associated unicode number "\uNNNN" in Java in any IDE.

Further for single character, straight approach would be:

```
 char c = '\uNNNN';
System.out.println((int) c);
```

Update: List of Unicode ranges for Devanagri http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0900.pdf
To type in Hindi in notepad/IDE etc, search for software which which maps keyboard keys to specific Hindi letter and related grammaticle punctuations.

Comment: Where NNNN is the zero-padded hexadecimal number.